# How to pass an argument from a Rules event to a Rules action?

Tags: 6, rules

In Drupal 6, I have made a custom Rules action in code using `hook_rules_action_info()`. I want to create a rule that uses the Event: "After saving a new term", which is an Event provided by Rules in the module.

I want to make whatever taxonomy term has been created available to me in my action hook, how can I do this? Looking in `taxonomy.rules.inc` I see the following code for the Event:

```
function taxonomy_rules_event_info() 
{
  return array(
    'taxonomy_term_insert' => array(
      'label' => t('After saving a new term'),
      'module' => 'Taxonomy',
      'arguments' => rules_events_hook_taxonomy_term_arguments(t('created term')),
    )
  )
}
```

Judging by the Rules documentation for 6, I need to declare the following in my action hook:

```
$actions['mymodule_notifications_notify_discussion_flagged_users'] = array(
    'label' => t('Notify discussion flagged users'),
    'module' => 'System',
    'arguments' => array(
        'taxonomy_term' => array('type' => 'taxonomy_term', 'label' => t('Term'))
        )
    );
```

Then I can pass the `$term` argument to the function that will perform my actions. When I inspect `$term` using `dpm()`, I get the following object which is an array with one empty element:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aD8Zz3l.png]

Surely after the term has been created, this should contain some info about the taxonomy term? What am I doing wrong here?